# gurus donut tutorial ctrl + alt + number pad 0

Tags: camera

I am watching gurus donut tutorial and in the rendering video he says to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd> to get the camera to the place where I am at but when I press it, it takes me to this weird view inside the donut and I've tried everything but nothing is working.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Grab` tool to move the camera out of the doughnut?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant to do was Snap the camera to your Viewing angle (viewport location) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num0</kbd>. Instead, you accidentally only pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num0</kbd>, which sets the selected object as the Active Camera (I'm guessing you had your donut selected when you did this). To fix it, select your Camera in the viewport (or the outliner), and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> again, to make it the Active Camera again. Then, you can move it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num0</kbd>, or just snap to its view with <kbd>Num0</kbd>:

[image: Camera]